# compilation unit aborted, caught 1 fatal ERROR condition?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, debugging, common-lisp

I have some common lisp code that is behaving oddly. It's a TCP client/server application.

Unless I add `(sleep 0.01)` or similar at the end of my code, I get the following utterly unhelpful error message *after my program completes*. It is a very short-lived program, simply hosting a TCP server and testing that it can be connected to.

> ;
> ; compilation unit aborted
> ;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition

This doesn't happen every time, maybe 80% of the runs cause this. There is no context, no explanation.

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
(defmacro with-gensyms ((&rest names) &body body)
 `(let ,(loop for n in names collect `(,n (gensym)))
   ,@body))

(defmacro kilobytes (qty)
 (* qty 1024))

(defun is-sequence (sequence)
 (or (listp sequence) (vectorp sequence)))

(defmacro append-to (seq values)
 (with-gensyms (cached-values)
  `(let ((,cached-values ,values))
    (cond
     ((is-sequence ,cached-values)
      (setf ,seq (append ,seq (coerce ,cached-values 'list))))
     (t
      (setf ,seq (append ,seq (list ,cached-values))))))))

(defmacro remove-from (seq value)
 (with-gensyms (cached-value)
  `(let ((,cached-value ,value))
    (delete-if (lambda (value) (equalp value ,cached-value)) ,seq))))

(defclass tcp-server ()
 ((server-socket     :initform nil)
  (server-threads    :initform (list))))

(defgeneric start-server (this &key port bind-address buffer-length))
(defmethod start-server ((this tcp-server) &key (port 0) (bind-address #(127 0 0 1)) (buffer-length (kilobytes 10)))
 (with-slots (server-socket server-threads) this
  (when server-socket
   (error "Server already running"))
  (let ((backlog        5))
   (setf server-socket (make-instance 'sb-bsd-sockets:inet-socket :type :stream :protocol :tcp))
   (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-bind server-socket bind-address port)
   (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-listen server-socket backlog)
   (flet ((handle-connection (client-socket)
           (let ((buffer (make-array buffer-length :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8) :fill-pointer t)))
            (catch 'eof
             (loop
              while (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-open-p client-socket)
              do (let ((length (nth-value 1 (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-receive client-socket buffer nil))))
                  (when (eq 0 length)
                   (throw 'eof nil)))))
            (sb-bsd-sockets::socket-close client-socket)
            (remove-from server-threads sb-thread:*current-thread*))))
    (sb-thread:make-thread
     (lambda ()
      (loop
       while (and server-socket (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-open-p server-socket))
       do
        (let ((client-socket (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-accept server-socket)))                                              ;; Listen for incoming connections
         (append-to server-threads
                    (sb-thread:make-thread #'handle-connection :name "Connection handler" :arguments client-socket))))  ;; Spawn a process to handle the connection))
      (remove-from server-threads sb-thread:*current-thread*))
     :name "Server")))
  nil))

(defun start-tcp-server (&key (port 0) (bind-address #(127 0 0 1)) (buffer-length (kilobytes 10)))
 (let ((server (make-instance 'tcp-server)))
  (start-server server :port port :bind-address bind-address :buffer-length buffer-length)
  server))

(defgeneric stop-server (this))
(defmethod stop-server ((this tcp-server))
 (with-slots (server-socket server-threads) this
  (unless server-socket
   (error "Server not running"))
  (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close server-socket)
  (setf server-socket nil)
  (loop for thread in (reverse server-threads)
   ; do (sb-thread:interrupt-thread thread 'sb-thread:abort-thread))
   do (sb-thread:terminate-thread thread))
  (loop for thread in (reverse server-threads)
   do (sb-thread:join-thread thread :default nil))))

(defgeneric server-running? (this))
(defmethod server-running? ((this tcp-server))
 (if (slot-value this 'server-socket) t nil))

(defgeneric server-port (this))
(defmethod server-port ((this tcp-server))
 (nth-value 1 (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-name (slot-value this 'server-socket))))

(let ((server-instance             nil))
 (defun deltabackup-start-server (&key (port 0) (bind-address #(127 0 0 1)) (buffer-length (kilobytes 10)))
  (setf server-instance (start-tcp-server :port           port
                                          :bind-address   bind-address
                                          :buffer-length  buffer-length))
  nil)

 (defun deltabackup-stop-server ()
  (unless server-instance
   (error "Server not running"))
  (stop-server server-instance)
  (setf server-instance nil))

 (defun deltabackup-server-running? ()
  (server-running? server-instance))

 (defun deltabackup-server-port ()
  (server-port server-instance)))

(defmacro with-tcp-client-connection (address port socket-var &body body-forms)
 (with-gensyms (client-socket)
  `(let* ((,client-socket (make-instance 'sb-bsd-sockets:inet-socket :type :stream :protocol :tcp))
          (,socket-var    ,client-socket))   ; duplicate this, to prevent body-form modifying the original
    (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-connect ,client-socket ,address ,port)
    (unless ,client-socket
     (error "Failed to connect"))
    ,@body-forms
    (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close ,client-socket))))

(defmacro with-running-server ( (&optional (port 0)) &body body-forms)
 `(progn
   (deltabackup-start-server :port ,port)
   (unless (deltabackup-server-running?)
    (error "Server did not run"))
   ,@body-forms
   (deltabackup-stop-server)))

(with-running-server ()
 (with-tcp-client-connection #(127 0 0 1) (deltabackup-server-port) client-socket
  client-socket))
```

Using SBCL common lisp.

Comment: Don't compare numbers with EQ.

Comment: Who does compile what compilation unit?

Comment: Why not? And what should I use instead? And I don't understand your question. I'm using sbcl.

Comment: `=` would be the correct choice for numeric equality. You should also use `RETURN` instead of `CATCH`/`THROW`.

Comment: I can't use `return` because that is only valid in an extended loop; and furthermore, using multiple exclusive `when` clauses cannot be done in an extended loop.

Comment: In any event, none of these comments actually address the problem at hand.

Comment: You can use (return) in a simple loop just fine.

Comment: The error message that you've pasted together with your code snippets are not sufficient to really help you.  The message is a compiler message, though, and your suggestion that sleeping a little while helps suggest that you have a race condition which is probably caused by how you compile and start your program.  If you want real help, post the complete code.

Comment: @hans23 Posting the complete code would not be feasible. It's in several files and reasonably long. How can I get the compiler to give me more information than "an error occurred"?

Comment: @SodAlmighty You don't need to post the whole code; remove everything that doesn't affect the problem and post the minimum amount of code that still reproduces the problem. Are you using `COMPILE` or `EVAL-WHEN` anywhere in your code? Also, have you defined any macros which might accidentally run code that's supposed to be returned in the expansion, causing your program to be run during macroexpansion?

Comment: I have now done so. The code causes the error perhaps 80% of the times it is run.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to happen for me on Linux + SBCL 1.3.2. Looking through the code quickly, one thing I notice is your `REMOVE-FROM`-macro. Two problems with it: 1) It's unnecessary. `DELETE` takes a keyword argument `TEST` which allows you to specify what to use for comparison (to remove a specific thread, you should use `EQ`). 2) You have to use the return value from `DELETE`. While it may modify the original sequence correctly, that's a side effect that can't be relied on. You probably also want to use a mutex to lock `SERVER-THREADS` when modifying it from multiple threads.

Comment: @jkiiski I have since fixed the `delete` call. I know the macro isn't strictly necessary, but it makes things clearer for me. Yes, a mutex might be a good idea. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get such a vague error message is that you're running directly from the command line and the error is happening in a thread. If you can get the error to happen in EMACS under SLIME, you'll get more detailed error information.

I ran your program from SLIME like this:

```
CL-USER> (loop repeat 100 do (load "/tmp/stackoverflow.lisp"))
```

...and got the following error in SLIME:

```
Socket error in "accept": EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
   [Condition of type SB-BSD-SOCKETS:BAD-FILE-DESCRIPTOR-ERROR]
```

So, something is going wrong on the server's end when you try to accept the connection. My theory is you have a race condition. In the server thread, you have this:

```
   (loop
    while (and server-socket (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-open-p server-socket))
    do
     (let ((client-socket (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-accept server-socket)))                                              ;; Listen for incoming connections
          ....))
```

...and in the client thread, you do this:

```
(defmethod stop-server ((this tcp-server))
 (with-slots (server-socket server-threads) this
  (unless server-socket
   (error "Server not running"))
  (sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close server-socket)
```

It is possible for `sb-bsd-sockets:socket-close` to be called and to finish *between* the call to `socket-open-p` and `socket-accept` in the server thread, so that `socket-accept` gets called on a closed socket.

Comment: True. But in the real world, this could happen anyway!

Comment: Also, I don't use EMACS because it's horrible. How can I get useful error messages on the commandline?

Comment: What do you mean "in the real world?" Debugging tools are part of the real world. For C++ there's GDB, for Lisp there's SLIME.

Comment: If you don't like EMACS, there's a SLIME for Vim, but I've never used it because I use EMACS for all Lisp development. The simplest partial solution would be to wrap your threads in a `handler-case` form and catch all exceptions. Store the exception object in a global variable, and then you can re-throw it from the REPL to see what information it contains. But you lose the stack trace that way.

Comment: It is also theoretically possible to implement a version of SLIME that runs directly in the Common Lisp image. The real work is done by SWANK, which is a CL library, and SLIME just communicates with it and provides a user interface.

Comment: I mean, in the real world, the client will not be under my control, and so could close the socket at any time. I don't use either EMACS or VIM - I'm using the Atom text editor and the commandline. I'm not getting a stack trace in the first place! That's the problem! How can I get a stack trace and a specific error message instead of "compilation unit aborted"?

Fixing the race condition isn't going to help. Eventually the client code and the server code will be running on different machines. I need Lisp to give me proper error messages and stack traces, so I know where to handle the errors!

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/3hzfsz/how_do_you_deploy_your_lisp_web_apps/) that was asked on Reddit about how to deploy Lisp apps.

Comment: Sadly, the Atom plugin is very broken.